# XeTeX + hyperref: How to increase hyperlink clickable box width?

Tags: xetex, hyperref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
link\hyperlink{a}{\textsuperscript{1}}
\hypertarget{a}{target}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the clickable area is extremely small. I have tried adding blank spaces, phantoms, and `\makebox` to no avail.

Comment: What version of TeX are you using? I don't get your box with TeXlive 2022: https://imgur.com/a/EDSmQWg. Add `\listfiles` after `hyperref` and before `\begin{document}` and then copy and paste your log into the question please, the answer (if there is one that isn't upgrade) is likely dependent upon your package and TeX versions

Comment: @JamesT Overleaf with XeTeX. But I checked in my usual set up of MikTex with XeTeX that  I am getting the same as your output. But that's besides the point, I would still like the box to be considerably larger in width, for touchscreen viewing.

Comment: You should have mentioned xetex in the question, it is a xetex-specific issue see `\XeTeXLinkBox` in the hyprref manual

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, thank you that solves the issue.

Comment: (updated the title to make it clearer that it is about XeTeX )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link boxes tend to be smaller in XeLaTeX* you can use `\XeTeXLinkBox` to force the box wider.

You can use

```
\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{...}
```

to specify how much padding the command adds.

---

- It shouldn't be *that* small: apparently an issue with the pdf viewer used, but xetex linkboxes are tricky, and this command can often help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the output in the question? I get a larger box with xetex and imho it would be quite odd if it doesn't encompass the 1 by default.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no, I expect the image in the question is misleading (why I worded the answer as I did)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was able to reproduce, see https://imgur.com/5zoMTfS.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner looks like a problem of the pdf viewer of overleaf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was fast :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe you should give an alternative answer then, or should I try?

Answer (score 2):

As **Ulrike** pointed out in a comment, it seems to be a **issue with the Overleaf PDF viewer**.

```
% XeTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linkbordercolor={0 0 1}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item link\hyperlink{a}{\textsuperscript{1}}
    \item link\textsuperscript{\hyperlink{a}{1}} % This structure / order is more logical to me.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

### Adobe PDF Viewer

[image]

### Overleaf PDF Viewer

[image]

Comment: @UlrikeFischer FYI :)